# Can a user restore purchases if they cannot make payments?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

In IOS you can check if the user can make in app purchases with this:

```
 SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()
```

I was wondering, if the user cannot make payments can they still restore purchases (for example if the app has just been reinstalled if the user can tap a restore purchase button to get back their inapp purchases)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restore purchase functionality will pick up the iTunes credentials from Settings and hit the Server for with those details alongside the app details. So if there ever has been a purchase made from that account for that app, then the user will receive his purchase otherwise blank response, which needs to be handled on client side.

Comment: I meant blank response. Thanks for pointing out, have edited the post for same.
And as for handling it, you can handle it as per your need. You can show an appropriate message to the user or you can play a loud sound as well ;)